# How do I delete a hidden HTML element?

Tags: javascript, nodes, element, hidden

I'm trying to delete an HTML element after changing its visibility to `hidden`, but I get the following error when I run [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/wraithmonster/CKj6r/2/). It looks like I can't get a handle on the element because it is hidden.

> Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 elementHidden

Is there any way to delete a node that is hidden using *pure JavaScript*? Due to conflicts, I can't use any libraries like jQuery.

---

*code from jsFiddle*

```
function elementHidden(e) {
    if (!e.target.style.opacity) {
        console.log('Delete this mofo!'); 
        document.removeChild(e.target.parent, e.target);
    }
}

document.getElementById("curtain").addEventListener('click', elementHidden, false);
```

Comment: How are you trying to do that?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use `$("#thing-you-want-to-remove").remove();`.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem! Would you share your code? It would be nice if you can simulate the issue in JsFiddle.net :-)

Comment: `document.getElementById("someID").style.visibility = "visible";` + delete it?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a node, you must call https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild, it's not a method of the `document`. It does not matter whether it's a hidden element or not

```
function removeElement(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```